# Solve the following Differential Equation $x \ln x\ \mathrm{d}x+(y-\ln x\ \mathrm{d}y)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following equation:
$$x \ln x\ \mathrm{d}x+(y-\ln x\ \mathrm{d}y)=0$$
How can i solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a strange way to bracket - you sure you didn't mean $(y-\ln x) y'$ instead?

Comment: There ought to be a $dx$ somewhere.

Comment: @gt6989b,yes i'm sure. i also think this strange,Do you think this is an error writing the equation?

Comment: I'm certain of it. I'd recommend that you double-check that, and if that's how it's written, you should contact the question-writer, if possible, for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that there is no $dx$, I am assuming $dy$ just means $y' = dy/dx$ really.

So we must solve
$$
\begin{split}
0 &= y' x \ln x + y - y' \ln x = y + y' (x-1) \ln x \\
y &= y'(1-x) \ln x \\
\frac{y'}{y} &= \frac{1}{(1-x) \ln x} \\
\int \frac{dy}{y} &= \int \frac{dx}{(1-x) \ln x}
\end{split}
$$

and you can finish the arithmetic.

Comment: arithmetic seems more difficult than solving DE :) Let me read one more intent. If the eqn. was, $x \ln x \ \mathrm{d}y+(y-\ln x)dx=0$
it would have an integrating factor $1/x$.

Comment: @user40615 You are probably right :). I thought he meant $dy$ for the right term, but not htat it was meant to be $dx$ :).